# iOS - keeping a reference to the main UIViewController in a static singleton class

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have a static singleton class that I use to access the main UIViewController (which is created by the appdelegate), and through it all sub-UIViewControllers.

Here's how I declare it

```
@interface mySingleton : NSObject
{
    ViewController* m_viewController;
}
@property (nonatomic,assign) ViewController* m_viewController
```

And in the .m file, I get this error:

```
@synthesize m_viewController; // ERROR: Existing ivar "m_viewController" for unsafe_unretained property "m_viewController" must be __unsafe_unretained.
```

I solve this by putting __unsafe_unretained in the declaration as the error says, however..
is there any problems for me keeping a __unsafe_unretained property on the m_viewController? It represents the main menu of the app, and should never be deallocated. So it being a dangling pointer should never a problem due to it being released by the AppDelegate later on, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want m_viewController to be released, why not use `strong` instead of `assign`?

Also, since it's generally the app delegate that allocates the main view controller, and since the app delegate is accessible via the UIApplication singleton, why not keep the reference to the main view controller there instead of creating a separate class just to do that?